# I keep receiving AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'items' when I run a get request?

Tags: python, python-requests

I keep recieving the error: "AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'items'" when I try to do a get request using the request library.

below shows what I have already tried.

```py
gethooks = "https://api.github.com/repos/ORGANIZATION/REPO/hooks"
response = requests.get(gethooks, headers={"Authorization: token GITHUBTOKEN"})
print(response)
```

I expect to receive a JSON with information on that repos webhooks, but instead recieve that error.

Comment: You are specifying a set for the `headers=` parameter, when it needs to be a dictionary.

Answer (score 9):

**You forget to commas in `"token GITHUBTOKEN"`**

```
import requests
gethooks= "https://api.github.com/repos/ORGANIZATION/REPO/hooks"
headers={"Authorization": "token GITHUBTOKEN"}
response = requests.get(gethook, headers=headers)
print(response)
```

> you should try it. It will give you result

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
gethooks = "https://api.github.com/repos/ORGANIZATION/REPO/hooks"
response = requests.get(gethooks, headers={'Authorization': 'token GITHUBTOKEN'})
print(response)
```

You're supposed to use a dictionary for headers.